# Deploy subdirectory with mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, mina

Is there a way to deploy a subdirectory of the repo through Mina? I've seen people using custom deploy strategy to achieve this with Capistrano and I would like to be able to do it with Mina.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this repo, https://github.com/thopham/mina-rsync, stage-sub-folder branch. Please see also my gist, https://gist.github.com/xlogan/10519195

Comment: This is a good reference, though it does not answer the question directly. I think I can learn from your idea to config deploy with git sub dir.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by wrapping a number of the setps in a `in_directory './rails' do` `end` block like this (my rails app is under the `rails` directory):

```
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    # stop accepting new workers
    invoke :'sidekiq:quiet'

    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.
    invoke :'git:clone'
    in_directory './rails' do
      invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
      invoke :'bundle:install'
      invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
      invoke :'deploy:cleanup'
    end    

    to :launch do
      in_directory './rails' do
        #invoke :'sidekiq:restart'
        invoke :'unicorn:restart'
      end
    end
  end
end
```