# Mina deployment subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, mina

How to deploy subdirectory from github with mina?

My master contains

```
|Dir_name
  |Rails-Project
  |other stuff
```

I would like to deploy Rails-Project

I found this question, but without a good answer [Deploy subdirectory with mina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524467/deploy-subdirectory-with-mina/23026122)